# Calendar not working with version 1.9.3

Tags: c#, .net, google-api-dotnet-client

My configuration is: VS2015, .NET 4.5.1, Orchard CMS, all Google nugets for 1.9.3, even the one not visible from Visual Studio directly downloaded. Last Calendar available which is 1.9.2.142.

I tried everything to connect on a fresh calendar: API Key, Cliend ID, Server Account. Nothing has been working. I correctly get the token but as soon as I try the following code

```
EventsResource.InsertRequest request = 
    service.Events.Insert(ev, calendarSettings.GoogleCalendarIds);
Event ev2 = request.Execute();
```

The execution freeze on Execute, nothing is sent.

So I reverted to 1.9.2 and there, the code is reduced, the only way to have it working is with `ServerAccount` using P12 certificate.

Has anybody succeeded using calendar with version 1.9.3? With which assembly configuration?

Comment: Well ... thanks for editing my text, it is certainly clearer. 
But aren't you afraid that editing everything like you do, may be mandated by Stack Overflow, could be a dangerous tendency which could lead to problems ?

Comment: How are you creating authentication for the code that is freezing?  what is ev? what is   calendarSettings.GoogleCalendarIds?  http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-authentication-with-c/

Comment: Using ServiceAccount with P12 the 1.9.3 freezes and the same code with 1.9.2 works.
In my previous code  ev is a Calendar Event. This code works with 1.9.2.
Using Fiddler it seems that in 1.9.3 the token is received but pgm stops working just after receiving it, no other request is sent as if we have lost an async call, sending it without any call back waiting to finalize.

Comment: @C.Surieux I'm not sure what you're referring to with your first comment, but as a general rule you should format code as code. Everything else in the edit seems like just cleaning up grammar. If you haven't yet, consider reading some of the Help Center, perhaps starting with [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I am using a ServiceAccount as well and had functional code (using an old beta release 1.7x). I have updated it to 1.9.3 and calls to first Execute command hangs.

Traced it down to the fact that the ClientServiceRequest class is using `ASYNC HttpClient` calls internally, even when you use the supposedly synchronous Execute command.

Check out the `ClientServiceRequest.cs`  in 1.9.3 file to see what I am referring to.

Comment: Yes I also see this and I tried to directly call ExecuteAsync with a .Result which normally means I won't miss the callback, but the problem does not change: Token received internally and nothing more, pgm stays blocked in a Monitor. May be a bad usage of last .Net code ?

Comment: C.Surieux,  An interesting aside - I am calling the Calendar API within an AJAX callback in a WebForms app. The first attempt hangs.  If I refresh the page and try again, it works.  This seems to confirm your observation that the token is received at some point, perhaps too late for the first attempt, but still hanging around for the second?

Comment: You have better results than me, I am calling this from a post to controller action and if I rerun the post  just after fiddler has detected the bearer token  reception (with 200), I have same freeze on Execute ?